# Как сделать автоматическое движение персонажа в Unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine-4, blueprint

Пишу простую 3D игру, в которой кубик, двигаясь по платформе должен прыгать через препятствия. Данный кубик должен двигаться автоматически по платформе (вперед) а пользователь может только нажимать на пробел когда надо прыгать. Вот собственно и вопрос, как мне сделать это автоматическое движение вперед?

Единственно что я нашел в интернете для движения это использования `Move Component To` и там можно указывать куда и за сколько времени. Вот только возникла другая проблема, при использовании `Move Component To` мой персонаж (куб) просто проходит сквозь препятствия и стены. Если я ставлю настройки что бы он двигался вниз то он будет проходить даже сквозь платформу. Скажите пожалуйста какие функции мне надо использовать для автоматического движения? Как это обычно реализуют в играх? (Что бы естественно персонаж не мог проходить сквозь твердые предметы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще, в project settings->input добавляем axis mapping, и добавляем ее в виде ноды в blueprint персонажа. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Scale Value не надо ничего перетаскивать и ue4 будет считать что кнопка нажата и персонаж будет двигаться автоматически!